# what is this program doing exactly? (SAS)

Tags: sas

I was confused by the following SAS code. So, here, the SAS data set named WORK.SALARY contains 10 observations for each department,and is currently ordered by Department. The following SAS program is submitted:

```
data WORK.TOTAL; 
     set WORK.SALARY(keep=Department MonthlyWageRate);
     by Department;
     if First.Department=1 then Payroll=0; 
     Payroll+(MonthlyWageRate*12); 
     if Last.Department=1; 
  run;
```

So, what exactly is First.Department and Last.Department? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data step calculates the total PAYROLL for each DEPARTMENT.

The `FIRST.` and `LAST.` variables are generated automatically when you use a `BY` statement. They are true when the current observation is the first (or last) observation in the BY group.   [How the DATA Step Identifies BY Groups](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/68089/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n01a08zkzy5igbn173zjz82zsi1s.htm)

The sum statement (Syntax: `var+expression;`) for `PAYROLL` means that the value of `PAYROLL` is retained (or carried over) to the next observation.

The `IF`/`THEN` statement will initializes the value to zero when a new group starts.

The subsetting `IF` statement will make sure that only the final observation for each department is output.

Answer (score 0):

As explained, it is calculating payroll for each department.

First.department assigns value =1 when a particular department id is encountered. last.department assigns a value =1 when the last record for the department is read.
So if you have :

```
Department  Wage
1            100
1            200
1            300
2            1000
2            2000
2            3000
```

With the first. and last. assigned, it will look like this:

```
Department  Wage         first.deaprtment     last.department
1            100             1                        0
1            200             0                        0
1            300             0                        1
2            1000            1                        0
2            2000            0                        0
2            3000            0                        1
```

Now you can follow your logic as to what happens when first.department = 1.

By the way, in your code, I dont see they are doing anything `if Last.Department=1;`

Comment: `if last.Department=1;` is a subsetting if. When false the current data step loop terminates and does not run any more statements, including the implied `OUTPUT` at the end of the loop.

Comment: Ah ok, it is an implicit termination of the loop.thank you